# How to prevent Deadlocks in Java using the Bakery Algorithm?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, deadlock, critical-section

Here is the code which is basically implements the Bakery Algorithm (in a class called Bakery) in order to protect the critical section in the Class Counter (from that class I will create my threads). The problem that I faced is that the program get stuck sometimes (and sometimes work perfectly i.e the counter variable is 20000 because there are 4 threads in my code). By the way Solution it is just an Interface contains the entrySection and the exitSection.

```
public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
     int threadNumbers = 4;
     
     Bakery solution = new Bakery(threadNumbers);

     ArrayList<Counter> threads = new ArrayList<Counter>();

     for(int i =0; i<threadNumbers;i++){
         threads.add(new Counter(i,solution));
     }
     for(int i =0; i<threadNumbers;i++){
         threads.get(i).start();
     }
     for(int i =0; i<threadNumbers;i++){
         
         threads.get(i).join();
     }
     System.out.println(Counter.counter);
 }
}
public class Counter extends Thread{
    static int counter;
    int id;
    private final Bakery solution;
    int count = 0;

    public Counter(int id,Bakery solution) {
        this.id= id;
        this.solution = solution;
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        for (int i=0;i<5000;i++){
            this.solution.entrySection(this);
             counter++;
             System.out.println(counter);
            this.solution.exitSection(this);

        }

    }
}
public class Bakery implements Solution{
    boolean[] Choosing;
    int[] Numbers;
    Bakery(int n){
        Choosing = new boolean[n];
        Numbers = new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n; i++) {
            Choosing[i] = false;
            Numbers[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void entrySection(Counter c) {
        Choosing[c.id] = true;
        int max = Numbers[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < Numbers.length; i++) {
            int currentNumber = Numbers[i];
            if (currentNumber > max) {
                max = currentNumber;
            }
        }
        Numbers[c.id] = max + 1;
        Choosing[c.id] = false;
        for(int i=0;i<Numbers.length; i++) {
            while(Choosing[i]){}
            while ((Numbers[i] != 0) && ((Numbers[i] < Numbers[c.id]) || ((Numbers[i] == Numbers[c.id]) && (i < c.id)))) {}
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void exitSection(Counter c) {
        Numbers[c.id] = 0;
    }
}
```

I tried to implement the bakery Algorithm and expecting the counter variable to be 20000.

Comment: The issue is that changes to variables written from one thread aren't immediately visible to other threads. You would need something like `volatile` but for arrays.

Comment: Generally, the [Java Memory Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) allows writing to a variable in one thread without it being propagated to other threads as long as happens-before relations are not violated and single-threaded semantics as-if they were executed sequentially (e.g. CPU caching). If you change a `boolean` in one thread, that change may not be visible to other threads. If you want a change to be propagated to other threads, you need to establish a happens-before relation/use something like `volatile` (which doesn't work on array elements).

Comment: I applied what you said, which is adding volatile before boolean also before int, but can I know why it is not visible to other thrads?

Comment: Adding `volatile` to an array results in an effect when reassigning the whole array. It does not affect array elements.

Comment: but when I don't add volatile to the int array, the program get stuck

Comment: but got another problem after executing multiple times I got answers like 19999 and 19998 what is the problem ?

Comment: It might be the same issue - the variables written not being viewed as updated

Comment: Re, "...I got answers like 19999 and 19998" Same thing. Different threads access the same `counter` variable, with no established "happens before" relationship between them. One thread could lock your home-made `Bakery` mutex, increment the variable, and then unlock the mutex. Then another thread could lock your `Bakery`, read the variable, and see the count _as if_ the first thread had never incremented it. That could not happen if you changed the program to use a `ReentrantLock` instead of your `Bakery` object because locking and unlocking a `ReentrantLock` _does_ establish "happens before."

Comment: There is no evidence of a deadlock here.

Comment: Did you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport's_bakery_algorithm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like many approaches to mutual exclusion and related forms of thread synchronization, the Bakery algorithm depends on particularly strong memory semantics -- stronger than you can safely rely upon in most environments that have multiple concurrent execution units.  Or even in some that don't.

In particular, as described on Wikipedia, [Lamport's Bakery algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport%27s_bakery_algorithm) contains several potential data races, and unless those are forestalled, its behavior in Java is undefined.  To make your implementation work reliably in Java, you need to fix data races involving

- the elements of `Bakery.Choosing`
- the elements of `Bakery.Number`
- `Counter.count`

You need to ensure that different threads will actually observe each others' writes to these, and that the reads and writes of any of them will not be reordered with respect to others of them.  Presumably, the objective is that the Bakery algorithm itself should inherently provide the needed synchronization for accesses to `Counter.count` inside a critical section, and done right, it will.  But that depends on ensuring correct memory semantics for all those array elements.

Using `synchronized` blocks or methods, or explicit locks, would moot the point of using the Bakery algorithm, so I imagine those are off the table.  `volatile` was raised in comments on the question, but it does not serve here because only fields and variables can be `volatile`, whereas you need a safe way to access array (or `List`) *elements*.

A reasonably natural solution that doesn't stray too far from the conventional description of the algorithm would involve using arrays or `List`s of [atomic](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) objects:

```
public class Bakery implements Solution{
    AtomicBoolean[] choosing;
    AtomicInteger[] numbers;

    Bakery(int n){
        choosing = new AtomicBoolean[n];
        numbers = new AtomicInteger[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            choosing[i] = new AtomicBoolean();  // defaults to false
            numbers[i] = new AtomicInteger();   // defaults to 0
        }
    }

    // ...
```

There is a variety of methods for accessing and modifying the value held by each atomic object, but the simple `get()` and `set()` methods of these should do what you need. These provide the same memory semantics as `volatile` reads and `volatile` writes, respectively.  (Some other access methods *do not* provide strong enough semantics.)